# htaccess internal masked redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I've been searching for hours on how to get say [www.xyz.com/payroll](http://www.xyz.com/payroll) to load the contents of [www.xyz.com/react](http://www.xyz.com/react) while still displaying [www.xyz.com/payroll](http://www.xyz.com/payroll) in the address bar

all i have so far is a basic redirect which changes the URL in the address bar to xyz.com/react:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^payroll/?$ /react [L]

    `# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN (mt) controlled settings
AddHandler php-latest .php
# END (mt) controlled settings
`
```

following code in htaccess already:

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please do mention from which file in backend payroll should be served? ie: index.php etc?

Comment: both payroll and react are folders in the main directory of the server

Comment: That rewriting rule at the top of what you posted does _not_ perform an external redirection. So there has to be some other factor that is responsible for that. Are there any other rewriting rules implemented? In the central http server configuration or in other distributed configuration files? And are you really sure you are not looking at cached results? Please test again using a fresh anonymous browser window. Then make a test request and monitor closely the responses you receive back inside the browser's development console. What happens? Please add that information to the question itself.